# multiple JOIN + SUM() query in LINQ -> can't loop in view

Tags: linq

I'm trying to translate an SQL query into LINQ, but after numerous attempts, I'm still not there... Can anyone help ?

This is my working SQL statement

```
SELECT        Users.email, SUM(Skills.level) AS SkillLevel
FROM            Skills INNER JOIN
                         SkillsPerUser ON Skills.pk_skill_id = SkillsPerUser.fk_skill_id INNER JOIN
                         Users ON SkillsPerUser.fk_user_id = Users.pk_userid
GROUP BY Users.email
ORDER BY SkillLevel DESC
```

This is what I came up with so far, but it lacks a sum() where I hard coded the number 3, that should be the sum of Skills.level:

```
var allSkillsPerUser = from u in dc.Users
                                   join spu in dc.SkillsPerUsers on u.pk_userid equals spu.fk_user_id
                                   join s in dc.Skills on spu.fk_skill_id equals s.pk_skill_id
                                   select new { Email = u.email, Level = s.level } into su
                                   group su by su.Email into gsu
                                   select new { Email = gsu.Key, SkillLevel = gsu.Sum(su => su.Level) };

            ViewBag.spu = allSkillsPerUser.ToList();
```

The view bag gives the following error (Email can't be found, while in the variables below you can see that they do exist...):
[image]

Comment: Let's see what you've attempted.

Comment: I've updated with my linq attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Skills
       .Join(context.SkillsPerUser, s => s.pk_skill_id, spu => spu.fk_skill_id, (s, spu) => new { Skill = s, SkillToUser = spu })
       .Join(context.Users, sspu => sspu.SkillToUser.fk_userId, u => u.pk_userid, (sspu, u) => new { Email = u.Email, SkillLevel = sspu.Skill.level })
       .GroupBy(su => su.Email)
       .Select(g => new { Email = g.Key, SkillLevel= g.Sum(su => su.Level) })
       .OrderByDescending(g => g.SkillLevel)
```

It's a bit simpler if you have navigation properties set up on your entities:

```
context.SkillsPerUser
       .Select(spu => new { Email = spu.User.email, Level = spu.Skill.level }) // guessing at the navigation property names here
       .GroupBy(su => su.Email)
       .Select(g => new { Email = g.Key, SkillLevel = g.Sum(su => su.Level) })
       .OrderByDescending(g => g.SkillLevel)
```

Or, using the query syntax

```
from u in dc.Users
join spu in dc.SkillsPerUsers on u.pk_userid equals spu.fk_user_id
join s in dc.Skills on spu.fk_skill_id equals s.pk_skill_id
select new { Email = u.email, Level = s.level } into su
group su by su.Email into gsu
select new { Email = gsu.Key, SkillLevel = gsu.Sum(su => su.Level) }
```

To order by the sum you can do this:

```
from u in dc.Users
join spu in dc.SkillsPerUsers on u.pk_userid equals spu.fk_user_id
join s in dc.Skills on spu.fk_skill_id equals s.pk_skill_id
select new { Email = u.email, Level = s.level } into su
group su by su.Email into gsu
select new { Email = gsu.Key, SkillLevel = gsu.Sum(su => su.Level) } into userSkills
orderby userSkills.SkillLevel descending
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with that kind of syntax. I have updated the question with my linq statement so far, but it lacks a sum.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no Sum command in the query syntax, you only get it with method syntax. But given what you've posted you only need to use the method in one place, I'll update my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, but it fails at the last part where you say: SkillLevel = gsu.Sum(su => su.level) . It doesn't know the "su.level"

Comment: Oops, called it Skill in that first Select by mistake, I've updated.

Comment: didn't see that myself, thanks a lot! Now the final piece of the puzzle is to get this thing looping in my view. As you can see on the screenshot, the data is there, but the loops says it doesn't recognize the attribute "Email". Any ideas on that one? I'm marking your reply as answer anyhow, thanks a lot!

Comment: Use dynamic instead of var, I suspect var will be casting to System.Object here.

Comment: Ok, rather than use an anonymous type, select into a view model, e.g. select new UserSkillsViewModel { Email = gsu.Key, SkillLevel = gsu.Sum(su => su.Level };

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'm new to this so I'm not sure how to create the UserSkillsViewModel, any tips are greatly appreciated, but I've already marked your answer as the right one. Thanks a lot for your help. Can't help but think this kind of job is so much easier and more natural in PHP MVC frameworks... :)

Comment: There should be a Model directory in your solution, you can just add a new class to that called UserSkillsViewModel (or whatever name you choose) with a property called Email and one called SkillLevel. Then update your query, and then your view to reference that class. It'll become easier as you get more familiar with it I think, if I had to do it in PHP I wouldn't even know where to begin :)

Comment: Hey Dave, I fixed it thanks to you. Not really sure why I need an extra class to represent the data, as MS doesn't allow anonymous types, but it's solved. Thanks a lot, I learned a lot with this example :)

Comment: Can I order by sum(su => su.level) DESC somehow? I seem to only be able to orderby before I select into the viewmodel, but at that moment I don't have the sum yet

Comment: I've updated with an example of how you might be able to do that as part of the query.